# The GUI is not moving properly

Tags: vb.net, webclient

I'm doing a little widget that shows the price of bitcoin using Binance API [here](https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=BTCEUR)

I'm not using Json format as I Just need to parse one string, eventhough I know many of you will say to use json. Anyway, I want to keep the software as simple as possible, but there is a little problem.
I'm downloading the source with webclient and Updating it using a timer.
I think I'm doing a mistake creating every time the new webclient because when I want to move the form, Is not properly mooving even if its not freezing.
The code I'm using is:

```
Private Sub webclientbtc()
       Dim wc As New Net.WebClient
       Dim WBTC As IO.Stream = Nothing
       wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
       WBTC = wc.OpenRead("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=BTCEUR")
       Dim btc As String
       Using rd As New IO.StreamReader(WBTC)
           btc = rd.ReadToEnd
       End Using
       '---------BTC PRICE---------'
       Dim textBefore As String = """lastPrice"":"""
           Dim textAfter As String = ""","
           Dim startPosition As Integer = btc.IndexOf(textBefore)
           startPosition += textBefore.Length
           Dim endPosition As Integer = btc.IndexOf(textAfter, startPosition)
       Dim textFound As String = btc.Substring(startPosition, endPosition - startPosition)
       Dim dNumber As Double = Val(textFound.ToString)
       Label1.Text = dNumber.ToString("n2")
       '-------------------------------------'
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
       webclientbtc()
   End Sub
```

Timer interval is on 1000 ms, which is great to keep me update.
Any idea on how I can avoid the creations of new webclient at every update?
Thanks

Comment: WebClient does have a .Dispose method so it should be disposed before creating another one. If you go with the Form level New WebClient find a place to dispose at the end of the application.

Comment: I m thinking to dispose it during timer tick, is it a good idea?

Comment: You can use a `Using` block in the `webclientbtc` method. The `End Using` disposes. The `Tick` event does not hold a reference to the `WebClient` so it cannot be disposed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplified, and using TAP:

```
Private wc as New WebClient()

Private Async Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim s = Await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=BTCEUR")
    Dim d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(s)
    Label1.Text = d("lastPrice")
End Sub
```

You need to reference newtonsoft json package and imports it, as well as imports system.collections.generic

Comment: Hi Caius, thanks, but as I said I want to keep it as simple as possible and I don't want to use Json now. Thanks

Comment: It's not difficult: in the latest VS2019 you paste the code, point to the red wiggly line under JsonConvert, click the lightbulb and choose "Install Package Newtonsoft.." at the bottom of the menu. The end. In older VS you right click the project, choose "Manage Nuget Packages", Click Browse, Type "Newtonsoft", Click the entry with nearly a billion downloads, Click Install, then paste the code. If you get any other red wiggly lines you point to them and get VB to do the imports for you. It's harder (and worse, and takes longer) to do your convoluted string chopping approach!

Comment: HI Caius you are completely right, I know. Json is the fastest approach  and the only "logic" solution. Anyway, since this is a simple widget for myself, I'm doing easy way also cause I want to parse high and low prices, change and change percentage data. For this reason my string approach is working and I'm confident with that. Just thinking that the problem is me not disposing the webclient.

Comment: *I'm doing easy way* - no. Nothing about your string cutting way is anywhere as easy as saying "hey, world's number one JSON parser, parse this for me, thanks". *also cause I want to parse high and low prices, change and change percentage data* - so you're admitting that you're then going to want to parse even more data.. what by, more string cutting? When I've already shown you the path, and you could write just 1 more line of code saying `d("priceChange")` or `d("highPrice")` and get the data you want? OK.. If you take nothing else away from this, at least make a single webclient and use TAP

Comment: Perhaps also worth mentioning that you're avoiding using a JSON parsing and instead effectively writing your own, but you're not going to similar efforts to manually download this data by writing your own HTTP client/whip out a TCP Socket, connect it up, push the bytes manually, read the response into a buffer, turn it from a byte array into a string.. So you're happy to use one high level abstraction helper class to do the downloading bit, but dead against using another high level JSON parsing library to make sense of what you downloaded - that doesn't really make any logical sense

Comment: Caius you are right and also it's very easy. It doesn't matter if it percy stuff, I have to do the correct way! You think is there a easier way to display just 2 decimals or I can use the solutions I posted in my first post?Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If the [answer by Caius Jard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66604224/1115360) is too good, you can avoid the use of a JSON deserialiser by using a regex:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1

    Dim tim As New Timer()

    Private Async Sub UpdateBtc(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ' temporarily disable the timer in case the web request takes a long time
        tim.Enabled = False

        ' using New Uri() makes sure it is a proper URI: 
        Dim url = New Uri("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=BTCEUR")
        Dim rawJson As String

        Using wb As New WebClient()
            rawJson = Await wb.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url)
        End Using

        Dim re = New Regex("""lastPrice"":\s*""([0-9.-]+)""")
        Dim lastPrice = re.Match(rawJson)?.Groups(1)?.Value

        Dim p As Decimal
        lblLastPrice.Text = If(Decimal.TryParse(lastPrice, p), p.ToString("N2"), "Fetch error.")

        tim.Enabled = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        UpdateBtc(Nothing, EventArgs.Empty)
        tim.Interval = 3000
        AddHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf UpdateBtc
        tim.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        If tim IsNot Nothing Then
            tim.Stop()
            RemoveHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf UpdateBtc
            tim.Dispose()
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

- There's no need to re-use the WebClient, creating it is not what is taking up the time.
- I prefer to instantiate timers myself: there is no requirement to do so.
- It is better to use descriptive names for controls: "Label1" tells you nothing.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for you answer. But as I said, Im not gonna use Json as this is a simple tool for myself and Json is still something its not fully clear to me.

Comment: @23rfwefaf This answer does not use JSON.